# Using GraalVM (scripting) within Wildfly/JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, classnotfoundexception, graalvm

I want to use GraalVM (version 22.0.0.2 with Java 17.0.2) to execute JavaScripts within Wildfly (version 26.0).

If I do have the following code:

```
System.out.println("Polyglot class: "+PolyglotException.class);
```

then my JSE unit test, started from Eclise, works fine. But if I call the same code within my EAR within Wildfly, I get an

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException
```

What's wrong? How can I inform Wildfly that the org.graalvm classes are available?

---

**Solution:**

Thanks to ehsavoie for the hint! I already had such an idea but did something wrong when testing.

You do have to do the following:

1. Put in your file `jboss-dependendt-structure.xml` something like:

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
       <deployment>
           <dependencies>
               <module name="org.graalvm" export="true"/>
           </dependencies>
       </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
2. define a file within `modules/org/graalvm/main/module.xml' with content like:

   ```
   <module name="org.graalvm" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.6">
       <properties>
           <property name="jboss.api" value="public"/>
       </properties>
       <dependencies>
           <system export="true">
               <paths>
                   <path name="org/graalvm/polyglot"/>
                   <!-- probably more packages will follow, but this is enough for the example -->
               </paths>
           </system>
       </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```

Sorry if there are any typos in upper examples. I hope, future Wildfly versions will maybe contain such a file automatically. For the moment, I am happy that it's working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to add dependency on the org.graavml.polyglot module in your application or expose it like what is done with the module /sun/scripting/main/